# Remove a blank space in a frame

Tags: beamer

I want to remove a blank space that appears in the header of a beamer presentation.

[image]

It's strange because if I change the Singapore theme into another one, the problem goes away.

This blank space has appeared since a re-installation of TexLive.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, if I use TeX Live 2017 (or earlier) the blank line is not present; I get different colors, however, both with TL 2017 and TL2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been fixed earlier today, see this commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/594db5d8f027c781c4ecc2b38907e04d2b16f043

Temporary workaround until a new beamer version is released: place https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your working folder.